# Mozilla "add on" sdk, simple-pref module, dynamic options (options that depend on previous options)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I wrote a Firefox add-on using the Mozilla add-on SDK that changes the color of certain websites based on their category.  I have four categories, and 10 websites in each.  I would like an radio option to be the first preference, and then the following preferences be dependent on whether the first preference is category 1, category 2, etc, etc.  Is this possible with simple-pref?  I cannot find any add-on sdk tutorials online besides Mozillas documentation (which is very sparse)

Comment: Instead of what you're doing, try this changing your thoguht logic to: Preferences don't depend on each other. But when you read the preference you take into account the values of the other preferences. So the dependency is calculated at run time, not stored. Think of preferences as a simple switch with a name. Switch One, Switch Two, Switch Three are either true or false. Now the dependency of, if switch one is on then it is impossible for switch 3 to be on, should be calcluated in your code, and you can apply the changes to the prefs branch if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Simple-prefs are static. You'd have to create your own html site and open that with a button from simple-prefs for a dynamic preferences interface for example.